# Report Service rdl Visual Studio 2008

Tags: reporting-services

```
1
1
Break ——> page 1
2
Break ——> page 2
1
Break ——> page 3
2
2
2
Break ——> page 4
```

Hi guys, I'm a stuck with a problem in above, can I page break without using group in RDL report service?
Help me, please.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Are these values inside tables?  If so you can set the Page Break Location on the table to END and the ResetPageNumber to True

Comment: Yes in one table, i don't know to break without using group